# How come I can't lookup associated array like this?

Tags: javascript

```
urlMap = {
    '0': {'6b4247404960fd4e418d242f3b7f0412': 'http://google.com', '123':'http://ibm.com'},
    '1': {'4c27ffaef99b7a6dbe838b46bcc09779' : 'http://yahoo.com', '456':'http://abc.com'}

};

    $(function() {
     var l = new Array(1,2,3,4);
     for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
          $("#"+i.toString()+".foo").change(function() {
           g = i.toString();
               window.location.href = urlMap[g][$(this).val()];
    })}});
```

I tried to use urlMap[i] it won't work. When I hardcode urlMap['0'] it works.

From Firebug, I see this

```
urlMap[g] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

window.location.href = urlMap[g][$(this).val()];
```

How am I suppose to lookup the dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, your `for` statement iterates from 0 to 3, but your `urlMap` object only has a `'0'` and `'1'` member...

Comment: I thought the change function is only called when there is a change. This is a select form, sorry if I didn't mention it already. When a user select something from options, one of the options will match the urlMap and redirects the users.

Comment: Also, element IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: @SLaks AFAIK they can in HTML5.  In any event, he has a "closure inside a loop" problem.

Comment: @Alnitak: You're right; I didn't catch that.

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, valid `id` values are different in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). :-) I tend to stick to HTML4's rules without colons or periods, as those IDs will be valid with all three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do. You have a map that has two entries, with the keys `"0"` and `"1"`, but you have a loop that's looping through the values 0, 1, 2, and 3, and then using those values to look up things in the map.

There are at least three problems with the quoted code:

1. You're trying to access the keys `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` of an object that only has the keys `"0"` and `"1"`.
2. You're creating a function in a loop that's a closure over the variable `i`, and so will only see the value of `i` as of *later*, then the closure is called. This is because closures receive a *live reference* to the variable, not a copy of its value when they're created. So all of your `click` handler functions will try to use the key `"4"` (the value of `i` after the loop completes), which doesn't exist in your map.
3. You're not declaring `g` anywhere, and so falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Here's my best guess at what you're actually trying to do:

```
urlMap = {
    '0': {'6b4247404960fd4e418d242f3b7f0412': 'http://google.com', '123':'http://ibm.com'},
    '1': {'4c27ffaef99b7a6dbe838b46bcc09779' : 'http://yahoo.com', '456':'http://abc.com'}

};

$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        $("#"+i.toString()+".foo").change(createHandler(i));
    }

    function createHandler(index) {
       return function() {
           window.location.href = urlMap[index][$(this).val()];
       };
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. I only try to access elements `"0"` and `"1"` of the map, since those are the only elements it has.
2. I use the `createHandler` function to ensure that the handler we create is closing over the `index` argument to `createHandler`, rather than the `i` value in the loop. The `index` argument won't change, whereas `i` will (as I mentioned) change as the loop continues.
3. I got rid of `g`, which we don't need, and just use `index` directly. Property names are *always* strings ([even when the object is an "array"](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)); any time you index into an object, if the index value you supply is a number, it'll get turned into a string, so you don't have to do it explicitly (though you might if you prefer).

Comment: Crowder. Thank you. I am not a Javascript writer.. pretty terrible one. So bear with me. Should .change() be called when there is actually an element selected?? I logged var g, and it is said "2", which does not exist in the map.  Thank you.

Comment: @Crowder. Thanks. The fix works. Now I understand what I did wrong. Thanks. TIme to read my old javascript book from O'realiy again!

Comment: @Crowder, mind to answer a small question? Why do we use return function, instead of just do XYZ, and then return? Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner: `createHandler` is *creating* a function and returning a reference to it. The function it returns is then used as the `change` handler. That function (the one `createHandler` creates) will be called when the `change` event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states, `urlMap[g]` does not exist.
You need to create it first.

Comment: Thank you. But how am I supposed to look it up? I can't hardcode urlMap['1']. var g is supposed to be '0' or '1', for example.

Comment: actually this means urlMap["2"] is not defined,

Comment: @CppLearner Put a `debugger;` statement before the problematical line. Open your console. Reload your page. Check the value of `g`.